# ¿Qué métodos para obtener los tipos de preguntas (tiempo, preferencias, ...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Tengo un csv con diferentes preguntas, respuestas y tipos de preguntas. Hasta ahora sólo he sido capaz de diferenciar las preguntas entre respuestas múltiples y la escala de gustos. Me gustaría más bien obtener el tipo de preguntas (cuándo pregunta, dónde pregunta, ...) así como las intenciones detrás de la pregunta (comer, dormir ...). Aquí está el csv:

```
    QID Questions   Answers QType
0   H1  When do you think your next vacation can start? ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']    Multiple Choice
1   H2  What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?    ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']    Multiple Choice
2   H3  What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?    ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']  Multiple Choice
3   H4  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'] Likert Scale
4   H5  Consumer Personality    ['']    Multiple Choice
5   H6  What is your preference of hotel check-in?  ['Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code', 'Online Keys using the mobile App']   Multiple Choice
6   H7  What is your preference of payment during Check-out?    ['Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Pay at KIOSK', 'Online payment using the mobile App'] Multiple Choice
7   H8  What is your preference of hotel cancellation / travel date change policy?  ['Travel date change is preferred at no cost', 'Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)', 'Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit']    Multiple Choice
8   H9  What is your preference of the guest policy?    ['Guests are allowed in living room with precautions', 'Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas', 'No guests are allowed inside hotel']  Multiple Choice
9   H10 What is your preference of the concierge service?   ['Regular concierge services', 'Online concierge service']  Multiple Choice
10  H11 Consumer Intentions ['']    Multiple Choice
```

Así que las categorías pueden ser las preguntas wh, las intenciones pueden ser... cualquier cosa relacionada con las intenciones, pero uno puede notar que algunas líneas no tienen respuestas (`['']`), estos son sólo títulos de sección de todo el cuestionario y deben ser detectados como tales.

Me codigo:

```
def classifier(l):
...     l = ast.literal_eval(f"{l}")
...     try:
...         l = list(map(int, l))
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
...     if not l:
...         return None
...     try: 
...         if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in l):
...             return "Likert Scale"
...         else:
...             return "Multiple Choice"
...     except:
...         return None
... 
... df.QType = df.apply(lambda row: classifier(row['Answers']), axis = 1)
df.QType
0       Multiple Choice
1       Multiple Choice
2       Multiple Choice
3          Likert Scale
4       Multiple Choice
             ...
```

## Actualizacion:

He tratado de conseguir las intenciones y diferenciar con sexos usando pavlov profundo:

```
!pip install fasttext

from deeppavlov import build_model, configs

CONFIG_PATH = configs.classifiers.intents_snips  # could also be configuration dictionary or string path or `pathlib.Path` instance

model = build_model(CONFIG_PATH, download=True)  # in case of necessity to download some data

model = build_model(CONFIG_PATH, download=False)  # otherwise

print(model(["What is the weather in Boston today?"]))

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
wb = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g...')
sheet = wb.worksheet('qa_cleaned_6')
data = sheet.get_all_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for question in df.Questions.head().iteritems():
  question= question[1]
  print("question: ",question , "type: ", model([question]))
```

Pero obtengo:

```
question:  When do you think your next vacation can start? type:  ['PlayMusic']
question:  What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)? type:  ['SearchScreeningEvent']
question:  What is your preferences of complementary breakfast? type:  ['SearchScreeningEvent']
question:  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food? type:  ['BookRestaurant']
question:  Consumer Personality type:  ['PlayMusic']
```